# Is this the way to change my asp.net mvc controller to call different methods using async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried changing my existing asp.net mvc controller code so that the user doesn't have to wait for the code to make different tasks such as db.update rows, call an external API and send an email confirmation.
I am unsure if this new async code will block my threads in an undesirable way.

This is my "sync" asp.net controller method as it used to be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CompletePackingItem(int packingId, int orderId, int nextOrderId)
{
    List<OrderItem> orders = new List<OrderItem>();
    OrderItem order = new BLOrder().GetOrder(orderId);

    if (order.HasBeenPaid && order.IsLabelPrinted && (order.Status == (int)BLOrder.OrderStatus.WaitingFor || order.Status == (int)BLOrder.OrderStatus.WorkingOn))
    {
        new Shoply.Data.Shared.DLWarehousePackingOperation().UpdateIsCompleted(order.OrderId);
        string htmledInvoice = new Shoply.Business.Invoice.BLInvoice().GetInvoiceHtmlFormatted(order.OrderId, false);
        byte[] pdfByted = BLOrdersPdfExport.SaveOrderAsPdf(htmledInvoice, false);

        new UserMailer().SendOrderShippedEmail(order.OrderId, pdfByted);
        new Shoply.Data.DLOrders().UpdateOrderToHasBeenSent(order.OrderId);

        decimal orderTotalInclDeliveryPrice = order.Total + order.DeliveryPrice;
        bool isSuccess = new QuickpayApiService().CapturePayment(order.TransactionId, orderTotalInclDeliveryPrice);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("index", new { packingId = packingId, orderId = nextOrderId });
}
```

This is my new version:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CompletePackingItem(int packingId, int orderId, int nextOrderId)
{
    List<OrderItem> orders = new List<OrderItem>();
    OrderItem order = new BLOrder().GetOrder(orderId);

    if (order.HasBeenPaid && order.IsLabelPrinted && (order.Status == (int)BLOrder.OrderStatus.WaitingFor || order.Status == (int)BLOrder.OrderStatus.WorkingOn))
    {
        new Shoply.Data.Shared.DLWarehousePackingOperation().UpdateIsCompleted(order.OrderId);

        Task.Run(() => AsyncCalling(order));
    }

    return RedirectToAction("index", new { packingId = packingId, orderId = nextOrderId });
}

private void AsyncCalling(OrderItem order)
{
    string htmledInvoice = new Shoply.Business.Invoice.BLInvoice().GetInvoiceHtmlFormatted(order.OrderId, false);
    byte[] pdfByted = BLOrdersPdfExport.SaveOrderAsPdf(htmledInvoice, false);

    new UserMailer().SendOrderShippedEmail(order.OrderId, pdfByted);
    new Shoply.Data.DLOrders().UpdateOrderToHasBeenSent(order.OrderId);

    decimal orderTotalInclDeliveryPrice = order.Total + order.DeliveryPrice;
    bool isSuccess = new QuickpayApiService().CapturePayment(order.TransactionId, orderTotalInclDeliveryPrice);
}
```

The new version is where I am using "async" and where I am hoping that it will jump directly back to the user and handle the tasks async and hopefully without unnecessary blocking of the threads.
Is this the correct way to call the tasks in an async way and also when I want a fireandforget way of handling it so that the controller will return immediately to the user?

Comment: Use a async controller probably https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526099/Asynchronous-Controller-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Side note: Consider moving your controller logic into a layer of it's own.

Comment: Move the logic out, use asynchrony, and implement a fire-forget queue if you want the context to return to the user without them having to wait for the operation to complete.

Comment: @Nick Developer, you seem to have pasted same code for New version and Old Version. Just noticed it now.

Comment: I have now updated the code.

Comment: Great. Check my new answer that I gave. Like I have explained, the user will see your page faster but it doesn't benefit the asp.net back end application in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you used Task.Run in the way described without waiting for it on main asp.net thread (i.e. `Task.Wait()`), then ASP.Net engine will finish executing the main thread without being blocked by Task.Run and return to browser quickly. Also, you will not be able to let the user know what's happened as a result of the code running in Task.Run method ( it might have thrown an exception or successfully executed and user will never know what happened with that part of code).

But, the asp.net thread pool thread will still be getting used when control has returned to browser since Task.Run may continue to run even after response is sent back to browser; so you are returning quickly to browser but your asp.net application is not gaining anything by this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your method signature from

```
private void AsyncCalling(OrderItem order)
```

to

```
private Task AsyncCalling(OrderItem order)
```

You are telling the compiler that "I am executing this task and yielding control back to you". Rest of the code looks fine to me.

Comment: Edits must be 6 characters or more so I'll say it here instead. `Task`, not `task`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it won't be blocking the threads in any way? This is the best way to do it ? And also the sending of email - should that method be async - or does that matter?

Comment: @NickDeveloper The method should be async for for sending emails else it will block the main thread. It won't be blocking any thread. There are other ways to do it but as per your requirement it is best way. Also please mark it as answer as it resolved your problem.

Comment: Is this the correct way to call the tasks in an async way and also when I want a fireandforget way of handling it so that the controller will return immediately to the user?